# How to write to file in bash without parsing?

Tags: bash, echo

While trying to write the following command in bash, with variable paths to a file in `/etc/languagetools/language_tool.sh`:

```
java -jar /path/to/languagetools/languagetool-commandline.jar "${@:1}"
```

I am experiencing some difficulties in preventing evaluation of the `"${@:1}"`. The function that performs the parsing contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
some_function() {
  local create_target_file=$(sudo touch 
  $LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_DIR/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_CONTROL_SCRIPTNAME)
  local make_readable=$(chmod 777 $LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_DIR/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_CONTROL_SCRIPTNAME)
  command_one="java -jar 
  $LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_DIR/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_SNAPSHOT_DIRNAME/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_FILENAME "
  command_two='${@:1}'
  local write_content_to_file=$(sudo sh -c "echo $command_one$command_two > $LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_DIR/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_CONTROL_SCRIPTNAME")
}
```

Which returns:

> sh: 1: Bad substitution

Hence, I was curious, how to write the command string to file, without parsing the content in the command?

Comment: Check if you are using bash or sh.  The '${@:1}' is bash extension.

Comment: Yes, I included the bash shebang in the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a command substitution or variable assignment. Just

```
echo "$command_one$command_two" > "$LANGUAGE_TOOL_TARGET_DIR/$LANGUAGE_TOOL_CONTROL_SCRIPTNAME"
```